# Two way databinding and change detection with child components in Angular 2-6

Tags: angular

I have a component I'm using from a parent component. It looks something like this:

```
export class AttributeComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() attribute: CharacterAttribute;
  @Output() attributeChange = new EventEmitter<CharacterAttribute>();

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.attributeChange.emit(this.attribute);
  }
}
```

My goal with this code was for any changes to the input model to be sent back to the parent. In the parent I use this code to create an instance:

```
<app-attribute [(attribute)]="character.str"></app-attribute>
```

Inside the component I have the following code for each property of the model:

```
<label>Base <input type="text" pInputText [(ngModel)]="attribute.base"></label>
```

However, ngOnChanges never fires and the binding is only one way. How can I make this a two way binding?

Comment: `ngOnChanges` is only designed to fire when Angular sets the `@Input` property-- it won't fire when changes are made to `attribute`

Comment: So ngOnChanges is only fired on creation of the component, how would I get two way data binding then?

Comment: It's not, it's also fired when the parent container passes in a new value. But if your changing the value yourself within `AttributeComponent` then just call `emit` at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NgOnChanges triggers before all other hooks, provided that your **@Inputs()** are setup correctly and you have attached proper **attributes** on the component's DOM in parent component.

Establish separate Input/Output flow or use subject or pass entire object (since a reference is passed you can freely modify its properties on both ends).

Comment: How would you pass the entire object?

Comment: Just pass an object from parent component: <child-component [propObj]="propObj"></child-component> 
If "propObj" will be an object, then it is not copied, but a reference is passed. 
Remember that because of 1way data flow even if data is updated (from child) parent will not re-render the difference (doesn't know about it). However the data on parent will update, the change will not be reflected in the DOM.

Comment: This is not very usefull if the parent doesn't now there are changes. How would I do it to get change notifications also?

Comment: That's why I added it as the last possible (from technical point of view -> you would have to manually trigger change detection on parent component) solution. If you have a shallow structure parent-child, or you don't want to pass this data across many lvls, then I would add single input and single output, the classic way. If you want to share the data in many places, then I suggest folliowing Subject pattern.

Comment: This just seems so extremly complicated for something so basic as simple two way data binding. If i understand it correctly you have to 1. Use a service, 2. have a separate component for EACH field, 3. use dochange and propagacte the changes with an emitter. All of witch requires a heap of code, so much in fact that using child components is much more difficult than simply writing everything in the main component for most opperations.

Comment: @devzero, for a simple parent-child relation follow the 1st option. single @input() prop and single @output() eventemitter. I found a post that kinda does what you want to do originally, but it has drawabacks: https://medium.com/@preethi.s/angular-custom-two-way-data-binding-3e618309d6c7
IMO, I'd stick with output/input. It is also the convention :)